# Args passing process python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, parameter-passing

I'm trying to learn paralelism in python with the multiprocessing library and I got some issues.

The following code:

```
def foo(x,r,lista):
    #lista[x] = x+5
    r[x]=lista[x]*5
def main():
    VetorResultado = 3*[None]
    VetorInput = []
    VetorInput.append(1)
    VetorInput.append(2)
    VetorInput.append(3)


    for x in range(0,3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(x,VetorResultado,VetorInput))
        p.start()
        p.join()
    print(VetorResultado)
```

Is printing: `[None, None, None]`

I want to change the values of the positions at the list. How can I do that??

Comment: We need a canonical dupe for "help, my multiprocessing program doesn't work because the docs do a terrible job of explaining the difference between multiprocessing and threads". People keep asking these questions, and they're reasonable questions, but they all have one of the same like 2 or 3 answers.

Comment: You created a separate process and it cannot change memory in the parent process.

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers, follow the `pool.map(..` example.

Comment: @stovlf I read about the pool library, but can I pass other parameters other than a iterable in the pool.map() method?